# Python: Assigning individual values to inputs received in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to make a to-do list right now, and I am using a while loop to get input from the user.

```
while True:
incomplete=input("Welcome to your to-do list (Press Q to end To-do list):")
if incomplete == "Q":
    break
```

But I don't know how assign the inputs gauged in the loop to variables
Please help, thank you.

Comment: IndentationError - [edit] and fix . Store the anwers somewhere - preferably a list.

Comment: This is not really a question for SO - if you do not know about list or tuple or dicts you need to do more tutorials, not ask here. Use the default tutorial to start learning the language, SO can not teach it to you. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: @PatrickArtner,ok, will do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a list to keep track of inputs when you don't know how many they are

```
lst = []
while True:
    incomplete = input("Welcome to your to-do list (Press Q to end To-do list):")
    if incomplete == "Q":
        break
    else:
        lst.append(incomplete)
print(lst)
```